# Should I always use CookieSyncManager with CookieManager?

Tags: android, cookies

If I have to pass a `Cookie` to a `WebView`, then I have to call

> CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie();

before `WebView.loadUrl()` API.

Should I also call

> CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync()

If yes, why ?

To be more general, When and where `CookieSyncManager` should be used with `CookieManager` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CookieManager allows you to remove/add/... your Cookies.

The CookieSyncManager should be called when you want to persist the cookies. If you don't call it, it will remain in the RAM ([see documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html)).

Comment: So `CookieSyncManager` may not be used at all ?

Comment: Yes! But, if you want to keep the cookies "forever" (unless the user delete them through the settings menu), you have to use the `CookieSyncManager`.

Comment: It would seem that on my device (Android 2.2), its necessary to at least call `CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this)` or else the CookieManager will eventually throw an exception.  But it is working without `CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync()`.

Comment: @eternalmatt , yep , The cookie presist even when I reboot the device. Is it really need the `CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync()` ?